# Sketching the graph and finding the function by using the given.

Tags: calculus

A function f that is defined and continuous for $x\neq 0$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. f($2-{\sqrt 2}$) = $\sqrt[3]{1-1/\sqrt 2}$, f($\frac{2}{3}$) = $0$,  f(2) = $\sqrt[3]{2}$, f($2+{\sqrt 2}$) = $\sqrt[3]{1+1/\sqrt 2}$
2. $\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)$ = $-\infty$, $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ = $\infty$, $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)$ = $0$, $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ = $0$
3. $f^\prime$($x$) $<$ $0$ for $x$ $<$ $\frac{2}{3}$ and $x\neq 0$, and for $x$ $>$ $2$; $f^\prime$($x$) $>$ $0$ for $\frac{2}{3}$ $<$ x $<$ $2$
4. $\lim_{x \to \frac{2}{3}^-}f^\prime(x)$ = $ -\infty$,  $\lim_{x \to \frac{2}{3}^+}f^\prime(x)$ = $\infty$
5. $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ $<$ $0$ for $x$ $<$ $0$ and for $2-{\sqrt 2}$ $<$ $x$ $<$ $2+{\sqrt 2}$ and $x\neq \frac{2}{3}$;$f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ $>$ $0$ for $0$ $<$ $x$ $<$ $2-{\sqrt 2}$ and for $x$ $>$ $2+{\sqrt 2}$

The question asks to come up with function $f$($x$)$ = $ (a$x$ $+$ b)$^{c}$$x$$^{d}$ that satisfies 1-5 conditions. What are a, b, c and d?

I drew the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMzBv.png)and found that d is obviously -1 however I couldn't find a, b, and c. Please help.

Comment: You must have tried something. Please tell us what it is, and what parts of the question confuse you. If you don't show that you have expended some effort on the problem, your question is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: I have edited my question, thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since the left and right limits at zero are unequal (in fact, do not exist), $f$ is discontinuous at $0$, so that $d<0$. Since $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=0$, the factor $(ax+b)^c$ must vanish there, so that $c>0$ and $ax+b = r(3x-2)$ for some constant $r$. So rewriting, we get
$$f(x) = r^c(3x-2)^c x^d.$$
Next, $f(2)>0$ shows that $r^c>0$; assume going forward that in fact $r=1$, and we will try to fix things up later if that proves not to work. This gives
$$f(x) = (3x-2)^c x^d.$$
Then $f(2) = 2^{2c+d} = 2^{1/3}$, so that $2c+d = \frac{1}{3}$. Next,
\begin{align*}
f(2-\sqrt{2})f(2+\sqrt{2}) &= ((4-3\sqrt{2})(4+3\sqrt{2}))^c((2-\sqrt{2})(2+\sqrt{2}))^d \\
&= (-2)^c2^{d} = (-1)^c2^{c+d}\\
\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/3}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1/3}
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/3} = 2^{-1/3}.
\end{align*}
Since these two expressions must be equal, we see that $(-1)^c=1$ and $c+d = -\frac{1}{3}$.

Solving
\begin{align*}
  2c+d &= \phantom{-}\frac{1}{3}\\
\phantom{2}c+d &= -\frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
gives $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and $d=-1$, so that
$$f(x) = (2x-3)^{2/3}x^{-1}.$$
Although we did not use the various conditions on the derivatives, this function is easily seen to satisfy all of them.

A plot is shown below:

[image]